# Drupal webform and checksum

Tags: webform-civicrm, checksum

On Drupal 7 / CiviCRM 5.25 I have 2 webforms with .

Let's say

https://domain.net/subscribe?cid1=753&cs=98dfe492769469013e9bef06dbc2fb7b_1601628311_168
&
https://domain.net/update?cid1=753&cs=98dfe492769469013e9bef06dbc2fb7b_1601628311_168

If I send the links through CiviMail to a profile that is a normal (test) member, *update* is already pre-populated and *subscribe* isn't. Of course, I'm trying in an other web browser where I'm anonymous.

I can't understand why there is this difference. It's the same profile, both webforms have checksums.

Any hint about a parameter I could check, knowing that *subscribe* used to work until recently and the datas were auto filled?

Comment: Do both forms have CiviCRM processing enabled and the 'existing contact' checked?

Comment: thanks Rebecca, you showed me the way. 'existing contact' wasn't checked anymore!

Comment: Always good when it's a simple thing ;)

Comment: Rebecca - could you add that as an Answer and then Guillaume can accept it.